# What's an appropriate data structure for a matrix with random variable entries?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, data-structures, simulation

I'm currently working in an area that is related to simulation and trying to design a data structure that can include random variables within matrices. To motivate this let me say I have the following matrix:

```
[a b; c d]
```

I want to find a data structure that will allow for `a, b, c, d` to either be real numbers or random variables. As an example, let's say that `a = 1`, `b = -1`, `c = 2` but let `d` be a normally distributed random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

The data structure that I have in mind will give no value to `d`. However, I also want to be able to design a function that can take in the structure, simulate a `uniform(0,1)`, obtain a value for `d` using an inverse CDF and then spit out an actual matrix.

I have several ideas to do this (all related to the MATLAB `icdf` function) but would like to know how more experienced programmers would do this. In this application, it's important that the structure is as "lean" as possible since I will be working with very very large matrices and memory will be an issue.

**EDIT #1:**

Thank you all for the feedback. I have decided to use a cell structure and store random variables as function handles. To save some processing time for large scale applications, I have decided to reference the location of the random variables to save time during the "evaluation" part.

Comment: Are all the random elements to be supported always normally distributed and independent?  Or do you need to support other distributions and/or covariance?

Comment: Some more details about what these large matrices will look like will help us give you more specific solutions. In particular, will the random values be grouped into submatrices within the larger matrix, or will they be scattered around all over the larger matrix?

Comment: @aschepler: I need it to support user-defined random variables, as well as other generic random variable types (i.e. normal, beta, uniform etc.)

Comment: @gnovice: they will be scattered all over the larger matrix so I believe that I will also store the indices of the RVs instead of having to iterate over the matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create your matrix initially as a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) containing both numeric values and [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) to functions designed to generate a value for that entry. For your example, you could do the following:

```
generatorMatrix = {1 -1; 2 @randn};
```

Then you could create a function that takes a matrix of the above form, [evaluates the cells containing function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html), then combines the results with the numeric cell entries to [create a numeric matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) to use for further calculations:

```
function numMatrix = create_matrix(generatorMatrix)
  index = cellfun(@(c) isa(c,'function_handle'),...  %# Find function handles
                  generatorMatrix);
  generatorMatrix(index) = cellfun(@feval,...        %# Evaluate functions
                                   generatorMatrix(index),...
                                   'UniformOutput',false);
  numMatrix = cell2mat(generatorMatrix);  %# Change from cell to numeric matrix
end
```

Some additional things you can do would be to use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) to do more complicated things with built-in functions or create cell entries of varying size. This is illustrated by the following sample matrix, which can be used to create a matrix with the first row containing a 5 followed by 9 ones and the other 9 rows containing a 1 followed by 9 numbers drawn from a uniform distribution between 5 and 10:

```
generatorMatrix = {5 ones(1,9); ones(9,1) @() 5*rand(9)+5};
```

And each time this matrix is passed to `create_matrix` it will create a new 10-by-10 matrix where the 9-by-9 submatrix will contain a different set of random values.

---

**An alternative solution...**

If your matrix can be easily broken into blocks of submatrices (as in the second example above) then using a cell array to store numeric values and function handles may be your best option.

However, if the random values are single elements scattered sparsely throughout the entire matrix, then a variation similar to what [user57368 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635654/matlab-appropriate-data-structure-for-a-matrix-with-random-variable-entries/4635888#4635888) may work better. You could store your matrix data in three parts: a numeric matrix with placeholders (such as [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html)) where the randomly-generated values will go, an index vector containing [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511) of the positions of the randomly-generated values, and a cell array of the same length as the index vector containing [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) for the functions to be used to generate the random values. To make things easier, you can even store these three pieces of data in a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html).

As an example, the following defines a 3-by-3 matrix with 3 random values stored in indices 2, 4, and 9 and drawn respectively from a [normal distribution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html), a [uniform distribution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) from 5 to 10, and an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates):

```
matData = struct('numMatrix',[1 nan 3; nan 2 4; 0 5 nan],...
                 'randIndex',[2 4 9],...
                 'randFcns',{{@randn , @() 5*rand+5 , @() -log(rand)/2}});
```

And you can define a new `create_matrix` function to easily create a matrix from this data:

```
function numMatrix = create_matrix(matData)
  numMatrix = matData.numMatrix;
  numMatrix(matData.randIndex) = cellfun(@feval,matData.randFcns);
end
```

Comment: If the matrix is very large and has a relatively small number of random variables, then the first `cellfun` call will waste a lot of time and thrash a lot of memory, since a cell array is an array of pointers, and each pointer would have to be dereferenced for the `isa` call. The method I suggested (using two arrays, the second one sparse) would almost certainly perform better (since `find` on a sparse array is almost a no-op), but makes the code more opaque.

Comment: @user57368: That's why I added the second example. It illustrates how you can break the matrix up among cells such that each cell contains an array instead of just a scalar value, so you end up with fewer total cells to operate on.

Comment: Ok. Now that you've added the @() I see how that would work. Definitely the cleanest way to handle it for a matrix that can be defined in just a few lines.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am currently thinking about heading the way you first described. I've decided to use a cell array with real entries and function handles for the random variables. I still have some issues regarding the random variable generation though - so I would appreciate any input on that.

Comment: @squall14414: Based on the extra information in your comments, I've added an alternative solution to my answer that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using NumPy, then masked arrays would be the obvious place to start, but I don't know of any equivalent in MATLAB. Cell arrays might not be compact enough, and if you did use a cell array, then you would have to come up with an efficient way to find the non-real entries and replace them with a sample from the right distribution.

Try using a regular or sparse matrix to hold the real values, and leave it at zero wherever you want a random variable. Then alongside that store a sparse matrix of the same shape whose non-zero entries correspond to the random variables in your matrix. If you want, the value of the entry in the second matrix can be used to indicate which distribution (ie. 1 for uniform, 2 for normal, etc.).

Whenever you want to get a purely real matrix to work with, you iterate over the non-zero values in the second matrix to convert them to samples, and then add that matrix to your first.

Comment: @user57368: Why would you want a sparse matrix for #2? You could simply put the data into a vector, saving both space and time.

Comment: You need to store both the definition of the random variable, and its location in the first matrix. A sparse matrix will do this just as well as a vector, but the code to convert the sparse matrix in to a matrix of the random samples should be cleaner, and the result would only need to be added to the real matrix.

Comment: @user57368: You could define the location in the first matrix by putting `NaN` wherever you want to have a random variable later.

Comment: I suppose so, but then you would have to iterate over the whole matrix to find and replace those NaNs. For a `m` by `n` matrix with `r` random variables, it's the difference between `O(mn+r)` and `O(r)` for the conversion process.